# grep: -P supports only unibyte and UTF-8 locales in Jenkins

Tags: bash, git, jenkins, grep

I have a shell script that is executing correctly in git bash in my local. However, when the same has been executed via Jenkins with the same git bash as the shell environment, it is failing with "grep: -P supports only unibyte and UTF-8 locales".

My local environment is on Windows and Jenkins too is on windows.

Can anyone please explain?

Comment: Does prepending your grep command with `LC_ALL=C` fix the issue?

Comment: No. prepending grep with LC_ALL=C didn't fix the issue.

Comment: @NishantKansal : Does exporting `LANG=en_EN.UTF-8` help? How does your regexp look like?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This should work :

```
LC_ALL=en_US.utf8 grep ...
```

Comment: Source? Explanation? Context? I would seem that this command needs to be prepended to grep, not just "set" as a variable. Why is that?

Comment: @daevski the command is equivalent to `export LC_ALL=en_US.utf8;  grep ...`, but the effect of `LC_ALL=en_US.utf8 grep ...` is limited to only grep.

Comment: I put `alias grep="LC_ALL=en_US.utf8 grep"` in `~/.bashrc` for git bash on windows

Answer (score 2):

For windows users running grep outside of bash (or git bash)

```
$Env:LC_ALL = 'en_US.utf8'
grep -P ...
```

Worked for me in powershell