# Git commit fails with `grep: -P supports only unibyte and UTF-8 locales`

Tags: windows, git

I'm using Windows 10 and `git 2.27.0.windows.1`. I'm working with Git using the CMD.

Running `git commit -m "things"` causes the following:

```
grep: -P supports only unibyte and UTF-8 locales
grep: -P supports only unibyte and UTF-8 locales
```

The commit doesn't seem to be commited.

I know of [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61456142/grep-p-supports-only-unibyte-and-utf-8-locales-in-jenkins), but the answer there doesn't seem to explain the problem at all. Guidance as to what's going on and how to solve it would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any hooks in `.git/hooks` other than the ones with `sample` in their names?

Comment: Probably a `pre-commit` hook : what does `dir .git\hooks\pre-commit` say, when you type this from the base directory of your git project ?

Answer (score 0):

If this is not linked to a pre-commit, try the same `git commit` in a CMD where you have set a simplified `PATH`, in order to exclude any other grep you might have (like one from Cygwin)

```sh
set PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
set GH=C:\path\to\git
set PATH=%GH%\bin;%GH%\usr\bin;%GH%\mingw64\bin;%PATH%
```